# Get Geo Coordinates in Windows 8 app running on Microsoft Surface

Tags: c#, gps, windows-runtime

I have a Windows 8 app. This app needs to retrieve the users latitude/longitude. This app works fine on my development machine. However, I tested it on one of the Microsoft Surface devices and it appears that the user's latitude/longitude are not being detected. From my understanding, the Surface does not have a gps sensor. However, it seems like I should be able to get an estimate of a user's latitude/longitude. I've noticed that Google Maps for instance can detect where I'm at.

Does anyone know how I can get my latitude / longitude on a Windows 8 device that does not have a GPS?

Thank you

Comment: If the Surface does not have a GPS sensor then you cannor use your current method that likely uses a GPS sensor ( you don't mention one way or another ). Post your code if you want help. Google Maps does some fancy stuff with Javascript.  Clearly without an internet connection the Surface RT will be unable to estimate your location no matter WHAT solution you implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very common problem for apps. Without a GPS sensor, you can't get... your GPS coordinates.

With an internet connection, you can approximate them in (few) cases, but in general it's not reliable enough (you can obtain a displacement of several kilometers !).

Just set your GPS feature as an option, or do not let users start your application if no GPS sensor is available on their machine.